# How bulkify trigger, facing issue while uploading data through data loader

Tags: trigger

I have 3 objects appointment,invoice and revenue.Invoice is having look up to appointment. There are some appointments which is having invoice and some appointments does not have invoice.There is a common field in both objects that is ecode. So here my requirement is in the revenue object i will put the ecode.If the ecode is present in the invoice then the revenue calculation should happen from invoice object.If the ecode does not present in the invoice then the calculation will happen from appointment. I have written the trigger also. So when i am performing the action manually the trigger is working fine.But when i am uploading through data loader since i have taken invoicelist.size the size is coming more than zero and the calculation is going to the second loop.

```
trigger Revenue_calculations on Revenue__c (before insert, before update) {

    Map<id,String>reids=new Map<id,String>();   
    set<string>ecode=new set<string>();
    set<integer>Bmonth=new set<integer>(); 
    List<Revenue__c> revlist=new List<Revenue__c>();
    List<Invoice__c>invlist=new List<Invoice__c>();

    List<Appointment__c >apps= new List<Appointment__c>();
    List<Appointment__c >apps2= new List<Appointment__c>();

    Decimal InvoiceFinalamount;   
    String clientname;
    String talentname;


    Decimal amount;

    for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){

        ecode.add(re.ECode__c);

    }

    apps= [select Contact_Talent__r.name,DOJ__c,Last_Working_Date__c,Employer__r.name, ECode__c  from Appointment__c where ECode__c IN:ecode];
    system.debug('***ecode**'+ecode);
    system.debug('&&Bmonth&&'+Bmonth);
    invlist=[select id,name,Emp_Code__c,Sub_Total__c,Status_of_Invoice__c,T from Invoice__c where Emp_Code__c IN:ecode AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Billing_Month__c) IN:Bmonth ];

    system.debug('%%%invlist%%'+invlist);

    system.debug('invlist.size()'+invlist.size());

    //when ecode is not in Invoice__c
    if(invlist.size()== 0 ){
        apps2=[select HR_Initial_BillRate__c,Initial_Billable_Hours_Days__c,ECode__c from Appointment__c where ECode__c IN:ecode ];
        system.debug('apps2***'+apps2);
        for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){
            amount=0;
            for(Appointment__c ap:apps2){
                if(ap.ECode__c ==re.ECode__c){
                    system.debug('inside new loop'+re.ECode__c);
                    amount= ap.HR_Initial_BillRate__c*66;
                    re.Revenue_Without_ST__c=amount;
                    re.invoice_exist__c =false;


                }

            }
        }
    }


    if( invlist.size() > 0)
    {
        for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){   
            ecode.add(re.ECode__c);
            Bmonth.add(re.Salary_Processed_Month__c.month());                
            integer count=0;
            InvoiceFinalamount=0;

            Integer count1=0;


            system.debug('++invlist size++'+invlist.size());
            for(Invoice__c Inv:invlist){
                system.debug('^^Inv.Emp_Code__c^^'+Inv.Emp_Code__c);
                system.debug('22Inv.Type_of_Invoices__c22'+Inv.Type_of_Invoices__c);
                system.debug('$$re.Invoice_Type__c$$'+Inv.Billing_Month__c);


                if(re.Invoice_Type__c==Inv.Type_of_Invoices__c ) {



                    if(re.ECode__c==Inv.Emp_Code__c && re.Salary_Processed_Month__c.month()==Inv.Billing_Month__c.month()&& re.Salary_Processed_Month__c.year()==Inv.Billing_Month__c.year() ){
                        count=count+1;
                        SYSTEM.DEBUG('Inv.Sub_Total__c+++++ '+Inv.Sub_Total__c);


                        InvoiceFinalamount+= Inv.Sub_Total__c*72;

                    }


                }

                system.debug('CCCcountCCC'+count);
                system.debug('$$InvoiceFinalamount$$'+InvoiceFinalamount);
            }




            for(Appointment__c ap :apps){  
                if(re.ECode__c == ap.ECode__c ){
                    re.Talent_Name__c=ap.Contact_Talent__r.name;

                    re.Client_Name__c=ap.Employer__r.name;
                    re.DOJ__c=ap.DOJ__c;
                    re.Last_Working_Date__c=ap.Last_Working_Date__c;
                    re.Actual_PO_value__c =ap.HR_Initial_BillRate__c;
                    re.Rate_pattern__c=ap.HR_Rate_Pattern__c;
                    re.Currency_Type__c=ap.Currency_Type__c;



                }
            }


            re.invoice_exist__c =true;
            re.Revenue_Without_ST__c=InvoiceFinalamount;

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: @SaumyaGaikwad whenever i am uploading through data loader there are ecodes which is having invoice and some are not having.Lets imagine i am creating 3 records and from that 2 records are having invoice and 1 record does not have. Since i have given invlist.size as condition i am getting invlist.size=2 here so the entire 3 records are going to the 2nd loop where i am calculatiog for records having invoice.Here the calculation for the 3rd record is coming wrong. I want to know how i can differentiate so that 1 record will go to he 1st loop and other 2 records will go to the 2nd loop.

Answer (score 0):

As in case of bulk operations, the records are manipulated in batches say a batch of 100, for those 100 records, trigger get executed just once.

When a loop executes,

```
for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){

        ecode.add(re.ECode__c);

    }
```

All the 100 records are in **trigger.new**. For some records there may be **Ecode__c** present in *Appointment__c* or *Invoice__c*. For those few records in the batch of 100 where **Ecode__c** is present in *Invoice__c* or *Appointment__c*  then the id gets add into the list `ecode.add(re.ECode__c);`

Thus the List is not empty for bulk operation and your trigger is not working successfully.

**Try using Maps:**

```
    Map<Id, Appointment__c > appsMap = new Map<Id, Appointment__c >([select Contact_Talent__r.name,DOJ__c,Last_Working_Date__c,Employer__r.name, ECode__c  from Appointment__c where ECode__c IN:ecode]; );
 Set<Id> recID = new Set<Id>();

    for(Revenue__c re:trigger.new){
       for(Appointment__c a : appsMap.values()){
          if(a.Ecode__c == re.Ecode__c){
             recId.add(re.id);
          }
       }
    }
if(recId.size() > 0){
    //your logic goes here
}
```

Comment: so how i can restrict this.can you please explain.

Comment: i followed your suggestion but for the record which is having invoice is going to both the loops now.here i am maping invoice values and searching  for(Invoice__c i:invMap.values()   ){
        if(re.Ecode__c==i.Emp_Code__c )        
        {
            recID1.add(re.id);
        }
         if(re.Ecode__c!=i.Emp_Code__c )
        {
            recID2.add(re.id);
        }} the particular record is adding to both recid1 & recid2